# Using private endpoints across Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-storage

If the two VNETs are peered, can a client in one VNET sitting in one Azure Subscription use [Private Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview) to a resource in another VNET setting in separate Azure Subscription?

Essentially, I am asking if Private Endpoints can be used across Azure subscriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course Yes. You can see the description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-endpoint-properties):

> The private endpoint can be reached from the same virtual network,
>   regionally peered VNets, globally peered VNets and on premises using
>   private VPN or ExpressRoute connections.

From this, it means the private endpoint can be reached from the globally peered VNets. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) is also a description for the global peering of VNet:

> The ability to transfer data between virtual networks across Azure
>   subscriptions, Azure Active Directory tenants, deployment models, and
>   Azure regions.

So finally, the conclusion according to the two descriptions is that the private endpoint can be accessed across different subscriptions.

Comment: Does that also mean if the networks are not peered then the private endpoint will not work?

Comment: @GirishAcharya Not Actually, you can use the private link, it's also a choice.

Comment: Taking this a step further, comparing with 'service endpoints'- I infer they do not work with peering and every subnet needing access to target resource needs creation of new service endpoint?